# Convertir int a Short

Tags: java

Tengo el código:

```
int x:

ArrayList < Short> lista;
```

Cómo convierto x a Short para poder agregarlo al arreglo dinámico lista mediante  la instrucción lista.add

Comment: haciendo cast a la variable x, ejemplo: `x=(Short)x;`

Comment: En lo posible hay que preferir trabajar con List y no directamente con ArrayList, ya que te amarras una estructura especifica y no es tan facil cambiar a otra distinta.

Comment: @ReneGarnica si solo quiere almacenar y luego consultar, con pocos datos, deberia usar List, pero si va a realizar muchas busquedas deberia usar ArrayList, no seria recomendable usar List para hacer busquedas en grandes datos, por que recorreria nodo por nodo la lista

Comment: @x-rw cuidado al hacer este tipo de cast. Los primitivos se pueden castear casi "libremente" entre ellos p.e. cast de `double` a `int` y viceversa con pérdida de información. En este caso, se trata de `Short`, una clase que es wrapper del primitivo `short`, por lo que el casteo a `Short` de una variable tipo `int` (primitivo) fallará. Lo que puedes hacer es primero castear el `int` a `short` (cuidado con la pérdida de información porque `short` tiene menor longitud) y luego castear de `short` a `Short`.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes realizar un *cast* de la variable, es decir, antes de guardarlo realizar el cambio de tipo de dato:

```
(short) x;
```

Realiza el cambio de x a *int*.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Aplicacion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 30;
        int y = 40;

        ArrayList<Short> lista = new ArrayList<Short>();

        lista.add((short) x);
        lista.add((short) y);

    }

}
```

Comment: Ivan Botero dejo esto como complemeto a tu pregunta espero no moleste. @Jairo Tovar El short es un tipo de datos es de 16 bits en Java con un valor mínimo de -32.768 y un valor máximo de 32.767 (ambos inclusive). y un int es por defecto de 32 bits con signo, tienes que tener esto en cuenta al hacer el cast y la perdida de informacion que esto con lleva, para no tener comportamientos  inesperados.